# Login page to another activity won't work

Tags: java, android

so I'm just finishing up my first app that I'm developing and after I made sure everything worked I added a new activity as a login activity, changed it from the android manifest so it would launch it first and I copy-pasted a code I had from another app i tried to make and simply changed the intent parameter so it would go to the activity I created in this project. However the app keeps crashing and after looking thorugh the logs it says that there in a problem at a certain line where it's empty. I'll paste the code here and maybe you can take a look through it

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button login;
    private EditText user;
    private EditText password;

    private String Username = "Admin";
    private String UserPassword = "12345";
    boolean isValid = false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user = findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        password =findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            //the problem seems to be here according to the log
            public void onClick(View v){

                String inputUser= user.getText().toString();
                String inputPassword =password.getText().toString();

                if(inputUser.isEmpty() || inputPassword.isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Va rugam sa introduceti toate datele", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{

                    isValid = validate(inputUser , inputPassword);

                    if(!isValid){


                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Date Incorecte!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    }else {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Ati reusit sa va logati", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }



                }



            }

        });
    }

    private boolean validate (String name, String password){

        if(name.equals(Username) && password.equals(UserPassword)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Error Stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mircea.bookrecyclerview, PID: 14617
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mircea.bookrecyclerview/com.mircea.bookrecyclerview.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.mircea.bookrecyclerview.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter User"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.691" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.581" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You should add the error stack trace.

Comment: I added it below the code

Comment: `login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);` Make sure the id of the button that you're accessing through `findViewById` is the same as of that in the layout XML file.

Comment: it's the same one I checked cause I copied it with the xml file alltogether

Comment: Can you add the layout file in the question too? Try adding @Override annotation above the onClick function

Comment: My bad man, it was the layout name, I forgot to replace

Answer (score 1):

Does your Manifest file for LoginActivity look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Can you click Build --> Clean Project and run?